# Qlistwidget mistake not defined

Tags: python, pyqt, qlistwidget

I would like to make a QListwidget with a scroll bar. I'm a complete beginner in pyqt and I'm trying to understand it. I though to create it with the following code but it is wrong.

```
self.list = QListWidget(self)
data = QListWidgetItem(list)
data.setText('1')

self.list = QListWidget(self)
    NameError: global name 'QListWidget' is not defined
```

If someone can explain my why it's wrong I'll appreciate that.

Comment: Is QListWidget a method of the module? Say the module was named 'pyqt', wouldn't you have to call `import pyqt` and then `self.list = pyqt.QListWidget(self)` ?

Comment: It seems you're also a python beginner,  I would suggest reading through the tutorials: https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 4):

QListWidget is defined under QtGui. So you need to reference that in some way. 
Either you could do `from PyQt4.QtGui import QListWidget` or as in the example below explicitly say where it is located.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.list = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        self.list.addItems([str(i) for i in range(10)])
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.list)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    ex = MyWidget()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```